Check whether given function defines a norm on $C[0,1]$.
Prove or disprove, if $w(x)>0$ for $0<x<1$, then $\|\cdot\|_w$ defines a norm on $C[0,1]$ , where $$\|f\|_w=\sup\{ {w(x)|f(x)| : x\in [0,1]\}}$$
I think this is not a norm, here is my counterexample: Define
$$w(x) =
\begin{cases}
1/x,  & \text{$0<x<1$} \\
1 , & \text{$x=0,1$}
\end{cases}$$
and let $f(x)=1 ,\forall x \in[0,1]$ .
Now $\|f\|_w=\infty$ hence this is not a norm on $C[0,1]$.
Note: We are not working on extended norms.
Is it correct?

Looks perfectly fine to me.

@温泽海 Thank you.

Should $w$ be an element of $C[0,1]$?
